# Code instrumentation

Tags: .net, system.diagnostics

How important is it to instrument code and is code instrumentation considered a quality attribute for code???

By instrumentation I mean placing code for diagnostics like trace statements and using performance counters where necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Often the only way a system administrator can investigate an issue without access to the source code is through instrumentation.  Consider the actions you perform when you have a problem in Windows - you might check the event log, check the memory usage, disk access and possibly other counters.  Without having access to this instrumentation you might not be able to determine the cause of any problems.

Of course the real value of instrumentation depends on the scale of your market and the size of your application.  If you have a small number of customers and are willing to help them troubleshoot problems, instrumentation might not be useful (as you can often look at the code and see what went wrong).  If you expect your customers to fend for themselves and your application is large enough that things can go wrong without obvious causes, instrumentation is essential.

Instrumentation does not affect code quality at all (code quality is about how easy code is to read, browse, and change), but it does affect product quality if it makes the product easier to support.

Comment: Thanks Greg this makes a lot of sense.